# How to encrypt this using caesar cipher?

Tags: substitution-cipher, notation

I recently had an [exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MzPk.jpg) that read:

> Encrypt the message "**easy question**" using Caesar Cipher defined as:
>   C=E(P)=(Pi+3) mod 26

What is this formula and how to solve it?

Comment: I assume *Pi* is supposed to be $P_i$?

Answer (score 5):

The formula reads:

- **C**: ciphertext of a character
- **E(P)**: encryption using Caesar of plaintext character =
- **(Pi + 3) mod 26**: index of character in alphabet, plus 3 (the key) and then  modulus 26, the size of the alphabet

So basically for `A` you encode the value to 0 and add 3, which gets you the value 3, which decodes back to `D`. For `Y` you use 24, add 3 and get 27. However, when you do mod 26 you get the value 2, which decodes back to `B`. So basically you go 3 characters to the right, wrapping around to `A` after you've reached `Z`.

Decryption is simply the reverse.

Answer (score 3):

If that notation hasn't been defined earlier in your course, then I'd say the assignment is way too vague and poorly written.  That said, knowing how a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) works, one can guess that it's telling you to:

1. split the plaintext message into individual letters,
2. map each plaintext letter into a number from 0 to 25, presumably using the map A → 0, B → 1, C → 2, ..., Y → 24, Z → 25,
3. add 3 to the number of each letter, and [reduce the result modulo 26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), and
4. convert the resulting numbers back into letters and join them together to obtain the encrypted message.

The formula given in the question does feature some fairly widespread notational conventions in crypto literature.  Specifically:

- $P$ often stands for the plaintext, and $C$ for the corresponding ciphertext.
- $P_i$ presumably stands for the $i$-th character of the plaintext string $P$ (and you're supposed to guess from this that the map $C_i = (P_i + 3) \bmod 3$ is supposed to be applied to every plaintext letter to obtain the corresponding ciphertext letter, even though the exercise doesn't actually say so).
- $E$ commonly stands for "encryption", such that $E(P)$ denotes the encryption of the plaintext message $P$.  (It's also common to write $E_K(P)$ for the encryption of $P$ using the key $K$.  Of course, the Caesar "cipher" doesn't actually *have* a key, unless you consider the additive constant 3 to be a key.)  Conversely, the letter $D$ is often used to denote the corresponding decryption function.

That said, the question as written definitely features some mangled notation.  If I were to rewrite it, I'd make it something like:

> Encrypt the message "EASYQUESTION" using the Caesar cipher defined as: $$C_i = (P_i + 3) \bmod 26,$$ where $P_i$ and $C_i$ represent the $i$-th letters of the plaintext and the ciphertext respectively, and the letters from A to Z are represented as the numbers from 0 to 25 for purposes of arithmetic.